# How to write python code to send data to Redis Database

Tags: python, android, computer-vision, helper, create-table

Need help on the code to send the data in the text box to my Redis Database after button pressed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zlyj.jpg)

Tried everything but with no success. I made a app to get the data from the server, but need to send the data from my program to the database

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.